# Are there any plans for IE9 support of webKit like text shadows?

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer, text, shadow

So problem is - IE shadow model is old and bad - text does not look better with it. Are there any plans for IE supporting WebKit/ Chrome / safary... looking like shadows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE9 Beta does not support the CSS3 text-shadow property.

Comment: I'm using text-shadow anyway in my new site, darn the torpedoes. They'll eventually support it.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 will continue Microsoft's legacy of producing the worst browser on the planet. Check at http://caniuse.com/ for updates on what IE9 might support.